# How can I use the Watson Assistant API to create an assistant?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I know how to use the Watson Assistant API to create a skill, but I also need to create an assistant and add the skill to it. How can I do this with Watson API or SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a new Assistant by API, you need to use the GUI from Watson Assistant. Concerning the skills, you could create a new one from API but it is really complex. I would suggest to start by creating a skill manually and then using APIs to handle tasks such as backup, switch, adding entities and so on. Essentially, a skill contains all the entities and intents + dialog + some logics. It's a big object in JSON format that is really complex to manipulate programmatically. This way, the user interface do helps the user in those tasks.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to create and update skills by API, but it really seems impossible to create and delete assistants automatically. I ended up needing to create assistants as slots and update related skills to reach my initial goal.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to this [IBM Watson Assistant REST API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2). The API is (currently?) limited to some tasks only, including management of sessions, environments and releases.

It is possible to provision Watson Assistant through the [Resource Controller API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-controller).